# ReferenceError: document is not defined Jest React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am publishing a react component to npm package, I added Webpack, babel, linting, and test to it, initially Webpack builds successfully, tests were running successfully, but then I added linting and remove node_modules folder and then install again using npm install to verify everything, at this point test breaks, Initially  I got jest not found error which I fixed by npm install jest, after that, got " ReferenceError: it is not defined", fixed by import { describe, expect, it } from "@jest/globals";, now getting " ReferenceError: document is not defined", tried multiple solutions like setting the "testEnvironment": "jsdom", tried to set global.document, but nothing is working, you can see the complete code at

https://github.com/asifsha/react-picker-cascader

[image]

Comment: Just in case, is `jsdom` still in your modules ?

Comment: Yes, I also install npm install jsdom, but getting same error

Comment: Hi @Asif, did you manage to fix it for jest@26.1.0? I am facing same problem. Global variables are not exposed independently; `global.describe` and `global.document` are present, however `describe` and `document` are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case node upgrade did the trick. I was using node v10.13.0 and upgraded to v10.16.0. It seems that minimum version required is v10.14.2 (at least for npm package babel-jest v26.1.0)